# Why kafka show error when try see offset?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I run command:

```
> /bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server 5.1.2.3:9092
> --group consumer-group1 --describe
```

and get this error:

> Error: Executing consumer group command failed due to Failed to get
>   offsets by times in 30000ms

all other in kafka work fine. 
Even i can dump zookeeper info :

```
> echo dump | nc 5.1.2.3 2181
```

and get response:

```
> SessionTracker dump: Session Sets (3): 0 expire at Wed Jan 28 05:16:42
> MSK 1970: 0 expire at Wed Jan 28 05:16:45 MSK 1970: 2 expire at Wed
> Jan 28 05:16:48 MSK 1970:
>         0x1008b4ba8b80000
>         0x10062424ea70003 ephemeral nodes dump: Sessions with Ephemerals (2): 0x1008b4ba8b80000:
>         /brokers/ids/1 0x10062424ea70003:
>         /controller
>         /brokers/ids/2
```

Comment: It seems that some of your topic's partitions have not been assigned a leader. Can you share the output of `kafka-topics --describe --zookeeper 5.1.2.3:2181 --topic myTopicName`

Comment: i check all my topic and each of them have som Leader. Some of them Leader: 1 , some Leader: 2.

Comment: this my output:
`Topic: SOME.TOPIC PartitionCount:10  ReplicationFactor:1  onfigs:
Topic: SOME.TOPIC      Partition: 0    Leader: 1       Replicas: 1     Isr: 1
Topic: SOME.TOPIC      Partition: 1    Leader: 1       Replicas: 1     Isr: 1
Topic: SOME.TOPIC      Partition: 2    Leader: 1       Replicas: 1     Isr: 1 `